# How to pass optional parameters to callback according to Typescript documentation?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was reading the do's and don'ts section of the Typescript documentation and there's a [don't about passing optional paramaters to a callback function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#optional-parameters-in-callbacks). Here's the example:

```
/* WRONG */
interface Fetcher {
  getObject(done: (data: any, elapsedTime?: number) => void): void;
}
```

But I'm wondering what if I really do need the elapsedTime to be optional, how I would go about doing it if not by making it explicitly optional with the ? decorator?

Comment: When you provide a *callback* to be executed, chances are that it will always be executed with the same number of arguments. There are very rare instances where you'd vary the amount of arguments a callback is invoked with. So, why make the parameter optional? You can always supply a callback which just takes `data` and ignores the second parameter. If you are going to vary the amount of arguments supplied you *most likely* have to re-evaluate your design. It might not be wrong but it's definitely a code smell, if a callback is not executed the same way.

Comment: It says "don't use optional parameters in callbacks *unless you really mean it*".  The point is that many people don't understand what they mean.  All functions have "optional parameters" from the point of view of the implementer; nobody can force you to use a parameter passed in, and TypeScript allows you to assign functions that don't care about their parameters to ones that do (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)).

Comment: So the question is... what do you really mean?  Do you have a use case for `Fetcher` that requires it to be optional?  It would behoove you to show it via [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), indicating how you create a `Fetcher` and how you use a `Fetcher`, and why it's important that the parameter be optional.

Comment: @jcalz I'm just wondering what the correct Typescript way of having an optional parameter on a callback should be because I didn't understand what my other option would be by just reading the documentation.

Comment: @Sara the question is whether or not you'd be invoking the callback with a variable number of argument. If it's always going to be the same (which it would be in most cases), then you don't actually *haver* optional parameters. If you invoke the callback with three parameters, then none of them are optional in the declaration. Any *caller* can then create a callback that takes three, two, one, or even zero arguments. Doesn't mean the others *aren't passed in", just that they are ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what if I really do need the elapsedTime to be optional,

If you really need it, then do it (using the `?`). But you very likely **don't** need it. Rather, it's more likely that you misunderstand what effect it will have. Making it optional means it's unpredictable what will be passed into the callback. For example:

```
const doRandomStuff = (callback: (elapsedTime?: number) => void) => {
  const before = Date.now();
  // do some stuff that takes time
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    callback(Date.now() - before);
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}

doRandomStuff((elapsed?: number) => {
  if (typeof elapsed === 'number') {
    console.log('elapsed', elapsed);
  } else {
    console.log('no elapsed time was received');
  }
});
```

More likely, what you're after is "you can use the elapsed time if you want, or not use it". But that's already the case with mandatory arguments, so you don't need to do anything to achieve that. For example:

```
const doPredictableStuff = (callback: (elapsedTime: number) => void) => {
  const before = Date.now();
  // do some stuff that takes time
  callback(Date.now() - before);
};

// This is legal
doPredictableStuff((elapsed) => {
  console.log('elapsed', elapsed);
});

// And so is this
doPredictableStuff(() => {
  console.log('done');
});
```